# swift - use an integer for loop in a variable's name

Tags: swift, for-loop, var

I' like to doe something like this :

```
for i in 0...3 {
let skspritenode\(i) = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Layer_\(i)")
self.addChild(skspritenode\(i))
}
```

that doesn't work because my skspritenode(i) is a let and not a string
and I have tried this:

```
for i in 0...3 {
let skspritenode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Layer_\(i)")
self.addchild(skspritenode)
}
```

which doesn't work because skspritenode already has a parent.

Is there a way of doing this in a for loop or do i have to declare each let separately? Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to name each node differently? `skspritenode` variable is scoped in `for` loop, thus the following code should work just fine:

```
for i in 0...3 {
  let skspritenode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Layer_\(i)")
  self.addchild(skspritenode)
}
```

Your point

> which doesn't work because skspritenode already has a parent

is incorrect, since you're creating new SKSpriteNode on each iteration.